# GridLayout doesn't seem on Design View

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to put an ImageView inside GridLayout but I Can't see on the designview.When I run the application I can see my image on the emulator screen.By the way nothing seems on the Design View before the edit that code on the styles.xml  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

I'm using SDK Version 28 and here's my xml files below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="376dp"
        android:layout_height="463dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in SDK 28. They will fix this in one of the future updates. Probably when its stable version is out. I've also encountered this problem, and what I do is that:

1. Test on emulator or a real device.

OR

2. Code my project in SDK 27 (this way I can see the layouts), and while testing on a device, I change it to SDK 28.